# Make Apache Ignite DiscoverSPI configuration over AWS ecs

Tags: java, docker, amazon-ecs, ignite

I want to configure some cluster over Amazon ECS, the problem is that the `TcpDiscoveryJdbcIpFinder` persist into the table `select * from tbl_addrs;` the wrong address. it uses the ip network of the docker, but the ip should be the private ip over ec2 instances to communicate with other dockers nodes in another instances. So I have this configuration

```
public TcpDiscoverySpi getTcpDiscoverySpi(){

    TcpDiscoverySpi spi = new TcpDiscoverySpi();

    String host = System.getenv("CONTAINER_HOST");
    System.out.println("Starting apache ignite on host -> " + host);
    spi.setLocalAddress(host);
    spi.setLocalPort(this.getDockerPort());

    TcpDiscoveryJdbcIpFinder ipFinder = new TcpDiscoveryJdbcIpFinder();

    ipFinder.setDataSource(this.dataSource);
    spi.setIpFinder(ipFinder);

    return spi;
  }
```

And I put the IP address of the ec2 instance which I'm getting from `http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/local-ipv4` I have the next exception

```
throw new IgniteSpiException("Failed to bind TCP server socket (possibly all ports in range " +
                "are in use) [firstPort=" + spi.locPort + ", lastPort=" + lastPort +
                ", addr=" + spi.locHost + ']');
```

And if I try to use the default network settings I get some ips of type 172.0.*.* and the nodes can't see each other.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would expect that `spi.setLocalAddress` will do the trick, but you can also try `igniteCfg.setLocalHost()`.

Have you tried AWS S3 or AWS ELB discovery? I think it is more appropriate here.